# Which Roman towns (outside of Italy) have been very well preserved?

Tags: ancient-rome

Are there Roman towns within Europe, North Africa and/or the Middle East that have been very well preserved? I am not referring to a specific temple, theater or stadium, but actual towns/(or small cities) which have remained well preserved for nearly 2000 years.

Comment: Perhaps you need to elaborate a bit on what you mean by "well preserved".  Do you mean streets & buildings still in use, or something that has been excavated & restored?  One example that's a little of both is Avenches (Roman Aventicum) in Switzerland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenches

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Roman_towns_and_cities_by_country might be helpful

Comment: Yes, I should be more specific in my question.  What I mean is which Roman towns outside of Italy are well preserved from an archaeological/ historical perspective.  In other words, which Roman towns-(outside of Italy), when seeing them either in person or in photos, appear to have stood the test of time, in terms of their overall appearance; referring to their streets, temples, stadiums, theaters and aqueducts.  Again, I am not referring to any specific building, but rather, their overall appearance.

Comment: Towns, such as Trier in NW Germany or Meridia in Southern Spain come to mind, though there are probably many others.

Comment: I could include Ephesus in Western Turkey, however, Ephesus was more of a city-(similar to Pompeii or Ostia) than a "town".

Comment: Perhaps you should explain better what differences a "town" from a "city", if that is relevant to the answer.